# Show other applications list in one app

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, app-store-connect

I going to show my other apps in one app. I know only one way to do that - just hardcoded icons, links and names of other applications, but it extremely inconvenient. Is there are way to reach itunesconnect's list of apps via some API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the iTunes lookup API to accomplish this. All you need is the developer ID of the account you want to lookup.

Here is a sample query for all of Facebook's apps:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=284882218&entity=software
```

The response contains a JSON object for the developer and then for each app, which includes any info you may want to grab such as the name or icon.

Comment: Just want to clarify. Apple probably does not forbid to show this data for other apps of same developer. Does Apple forbids to show apps of other developers?

Comment: I do not know of any rule explicit or otherwise that prevents any use of this API. Why would they forbid it? If I recall, there are plenty of apps in the app store that aggregate other apps to show things like discounts and updates. They no doubt use this API or something very similar.